# TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration when using zip in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I have two lists of lists and I am trying to `zip` the elements of each of inner lists together. I can zip them together just fine when I access just one element of each list, but I would like to do it in a `for` loop. Here's the code that runs fine:

```
combined = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(depth_lst[0], diameter_lst[0])]
```

When I try to use this same logic in a `for` loop I get an error:

```
dep_dia = []
for i in range(len(diameter_lst)):
    combined = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(depth_lst[i], diameter_lst[i])]
    dep_dia.append(combined)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-343ff6687d48> in <module>
      1 dep_dia = []
      2 for i in range(len(diameter_lst)):
----> 3     combined = [(a, b) for a, b in zip(depth_lst[i], diameter_lst[i])]
      4     dep_dia.append(combined)

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Is there a reason `zip` works when I index the lists of lists directly vs. in a loop?

Comment: No, the problem is probably that one of the elements in the lists is not iterable. Try to print out the specific `i` where the code stops working and check if the value you print out is an iterable.

Comment: This error indicates that you reach an element of `depth_lst` that is not an iterable. Is there any `None` or non-list element in `depth_lst`? You should add a debugging `print(depth_lst[i])` before the zipping line to check value of the element. BTW, `[(a,b) for a,b in zip(...)]` can be simplified in `list(zip(...))`

Comment: Thanks for the help! There was an empty list that was causing the issue.